# Jquery addClass to tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs, navigation, addclass

I have links (navigation tabs) in my page like this:

```
<body>
<div id="nav">
<a href="1" class="active">First link</a>
<a href="2" >Second link</a>
<a href="3" >Third link</a>
</div>
</body>
```

and I can't figure out why my jquery script doesn't work to change the class of the clicked link to active and to remove any class from other links.

Comment: is there any javascript associated with this code?

Comment: Are you aware of that **you didn't add the not working jQuery script**, right?

Comment: I can see why it doesn't work, there's no script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want something like:

```
$('#nav a').click(function(event){
    $(this).parent().find('a.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```